# Convert hours to days in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, timespan

I am pretty new to C# I have been researching but can not find specifically what I am looking for before I asked this question.

What is the best way to convert hours only to days in C?

If you know of any article or quick simple answer to point me to that would be great. I will keep looking though.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you must be asking for something other than the obvious answer, which is to divide the number of hours by 24, but if so, you need to elaborate to explain what you really want.

Comment: Yeah I could have been more specific but normally I would think if I am coming here to ask a question it usually means something more than some simple math. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try using a `TimeSpan` struct. Wehave some static methods to make those conversions, like: `TimeSpan.FromHours` and it will return a new `TimeSpan` and we can read the `TotalDays` property. Or you could create a method for it:

```
public static double ConvertHoursToTotalDays(double hours)
{
    TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours);
    
    return result.TotalDays;
}
```

And call it:

```
double days = ConvertHoursToTotalDays(120); // should be 5.0
```

Comment: Make sure you know the difference between [TotalDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) and [Days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) You may need TotalDays instead of Days depending if you want an answer like "1.5 days" for 36 hours (`Days` would return 1, and also have `12` in [Hours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply divide by 24(hours in a day) and you will gets number of days.

```
int hours = 48;

double days = hours/24;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I knew I could do it that way but I was looking more for a structure, function or something to use like the TimeSpan that Felipe mentioned below.

Comment: @zachr91185: If you are looking for inbuilt methods, then `Timespan` class is best. But that class also does the same thing, and will find the answer the way I calculated.