# Turning int to text in MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

The title might need changing.

I have a table that has a TurnTime_MinHours and a TurnTime_MaxHours column. Looks like this

```
TurnTime_MinHours | TurnTime_MaxHours
---------------------------------------
      0                     24             //represents 1 day
     24                     48             //represents 1-2 days
     24                     72             //represents 2-3 days
     24                     120            //represents 1-5 days
```

Now, the problem comes to the View part of my MVC application.  I want to show this data in a nice, user-friendly way such as "1 day", "1-3 days", "1-5 days" rather than the integer values.

I first tried making a small `switch case` function that would do this but I ran into the problem of converting my `int` fields to a `string` field.

I just implemented a ternary for a similar situation but I'm not sure if it would work in this case.
  ternary reference: [Handling tinyInt booleans with MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760855/handling-tinyint-booleans-with-mvc)

Comment: A simple method to [convert hours to days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182206/convert-hours-to-days-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this - you can add your ranges to a `Tuple<int, int>` and then use `TimeSpan.TotalDays` to convert:

**Update**: An alternate, less verbose way of handling ( I wouldn't reduce this any further due to readability: This method, however, sacrifices a bit of performance because it will run the 1st TimeSpan instance conversion even when not in use. Assuming that is only in one instance (when the range is 1 day), this may be acceptable, and it looks nicer.

```
Func<Tuple<int, int>, string> getDaysFromHoursAlternate = range =>
{
    string format = range.Item2 > 24 ? "{0} - {1} days" : "{1} day";
    return string.Format(format,
            TimeSpan.FromHours(range.Item1).TotalDays,
            TimeSpan.FromHours(range.Item2).TotalDays
    );
};
```

Original answer w/full code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Tuple<int, int>> ranges = new List<Tuple<int, int>>()
        {
            new Tuple<int, int>(0, 24),
            new Tuple<int, int>(24, 48),
            new Tuple<int, int>(24, 72),
            new Tuple<int, int>(24, 120)
        };

        Func<Tuple<int, int>, string> getDaysFromHours = range =>
        {
            string formatted;
            if (range.Item2 > 24)
            {
                formatted = string.Format(
                    "{0} - {1} days",
                    TimeSpan.FromHours(range.Item1).TotalDays,
                    TimeSpan.FromHours(range.Item2).TotalDays
                );
            }
            else
            {
                formatted = string.Format("{0} day",
                    TimeSpan.FromHours(range.Item2).TotalDays
                );
            }

            return formatted;
        };

        ranges.ForEach(r =>
            Console.WriteLine(getDaysFromHours(r))
        );

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```